# Silverlight Windows Phone http C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, http

I devloping application for Windows Phone 
I use Visual Studio express 2010 c# for Windows Phone
How to do request to web page wrom c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting any code from you (the usual what have you tried question), I can give you just a few links... You can use the [HpptWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) classes.
[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx) is a tutorial for both.